# What symbol conveys "save"?

Tags: icons, save, symbols, signifier

I have a text input field where the user enters an address. I am adding the ability to save the address to an address book. What should the icon look like to save? This is for smartphones so space is limited.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fId2YF.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

What symbol should the plus sign be, as plus isn't always a signifier for "save to address book".

Answer (score 4):

The Floppy disk icon is a common icon that's been engraved into the minds as the **Save** icon.

Apart from that, you could also use the Tick to signify **Done and Save**

[image: floppy]             [image: tick]

Ideally you should follow the guidelines specified for the Smartphone's OS.

Answer (score 2):

I like [Google Material Icons'](https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_add_location) Add Location icon:

[image: Google Material Icon: Add Location]

Comment: Thanks, though can anyone use it or is it copyrighted?

Comment: @Celeritas [We have made these icons available for you to incorporate them into your products under the Creative Common Attribution 4.0 International License (CC-BY 4.0). Feel free to remix and re-share these icons and documentation in your products. We'd love attribution in your app's about screen, but it's not required. The only thing we ask is that you not re-sell the icons themselves.](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/)

Comment: @Celeritas [The icons are available under the Apache License Version 2.0. We'd love attribution in your app's "about" screen, but it's not required. The only thing we ask is that you not re-sell these icons.](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/)

Comment: @Bob thanks, I ask because this is a preliminary prototype, so we don't exactly have a license document, or even an about screen yet.